# How to consume REST service from a MVC 4 web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rest

Can someone give me pointers on how to How to consume an external REST service from a MVC 4 web application? The services rely on an initial call with credentials base 64 encoded, then returns a token which is used for further web service queries.

I cannot find an easy primer on how to do this kind of thing, could someone help please?
I have all this working in classic ASP & JQuery but need to move over to an MVC 4 web application.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Here's an example of how you could send a GET request and use Basic Authentication:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://foo.com");
var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("john:secret");
var authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;
var response = client.GetAsync("/api/authenticate").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Once you have retrieved the access token you could make authenticated calls:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://foo.com");
string accessToken = ...
var authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearar", accessToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;
var response = client.GetAsync("/api/bar").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that, the first block works fine and gets a json array back as a string. Great. The problem for me now is how to extract items from the json?

Comment: You could define a class which will map to the properties of the JSON and then use the `ReadAsAsync<T>` method on the `response.Content` which will automatically parse the JSON to the class you defined. As an alternative you could manually parse the string response you have obtained using a JSON serializer in order to extract the information you are looking for in this JSON.

Comment: Darin thanks. What I am finding now is that having got the token back from the initial json response I cannot pass it on to the next rest call (nested  in the on success of the ajax call) which should send token received as authentication, plus query string params, and get back data Json array.